# Bug en bindeo de angular

Tags: angular, typescript, objeto, angular-material, component

Necesito ayuda con el bindeo de componentes de angular.

Tengo un componente que está compuesto por un select y un input del tipo texto donde en el select puedo seleccionar una descripción de un objeto y en el input ingreso la cantidad que quiero asignarle a este. En mi formulario tengo que poder seleccionar varios objetos con su cantidad, por lo que cada vez que selecciono uno y le asigno una cantidad con un boton lo guardo en un objeto y lo muestro con un chip para informárselo al usuario.

Me está sucediendo que cada vez que hago esto, en la colección, me reemplaza todos los ítems por el último seleccionado.

> *Nota:*
> *Angular CLI: Version 13.0.2 |*
> *npm 8.1.0*

```js
  anotherWork = new workModel();
  anotherMaterial = new materialModel();
  anotherMaterialList = new Array<materialModel>();

  //FORM CONTROLS
  clientControl = new FormControl();
  descriptionControl = new FormControl();
  costControl = new FormControl();
  employeesControl = new FormControl();
  materialsControl = new FormControl();
  isFinishedControl = new FormControl();
  //[...
  //...
  //...]
    materialDescriptionChange(desc:string){
    this.anotherMaterial.description = desc;
  }

  materialQuantityChange(quan:string){
    this.anotherMaterial.quantity = parseFloat(quan);
  }

  addMaterial(id:string){
    this.anotherMaterial.id = id;
    this.anotherMaterialList.push(this.anotherMaterial);
    console.log(this.anotherMaterialList);
  }
```

```html
    <!--MATERIALES | CHIPS / SELECT / INPUT NUMBER / BUTTON-->
    <p>
        <mat-form-field  class="form-field" *ngIf="anotherMaterialList.length > 0">
            <mat-chip-list >
                <mat-chip *ngFor="let wmt of anotherMaterialList" >
                    {{wmt.description}} ({{wmt.quantity}})
                </mat-chip>
            </mat-chip-list>
        </mat-form-field>
    </p>
    <p *ngIf="materialList !== undefined">
        <!-- <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="form-field-material-select"> -->
        <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="form-field-material-select">
            <mat-label>Materiales</mat-label>
            <mat-select #ma [formControl]="materialsControl" (selectionChange)="materialDescriptionChange(ma.triggerValue)">
                <mat-select-trigger>
                    <span *ngIf="materialsControl.value?.length > 0">
                        {{ma.triggerValue}}
                    </span>
                </mat-select-trigger>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let m of materialList" [value]="m.id">
                    {{m.description}} ({{m.quantity}})
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="form-field-material-input">
            <mat-label>Cantidad</mat-label>
            <input #q matInput placeholder="Cantidad" type="number" (change)="materialQuantityChange(q.value)" >
        </mat-form-field>
        <a (click)="addMaterial(ma.value)" color="primary" mat-raised-button class="form-field-material-button">
            <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
        </a> 
        
    </p>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se soluciono en este otro post de stackOverflow en ingles. [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72098581/bug-in-angular-binding)

Comment: El formato de [es.so] es de _preguntas y respuestas_, no de foro. La respuesta como tal debe ir _como respuesta_, no como edición de la pregunta o como comentario. Pon la solución como respuesta (en base a [answer]) y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Por último, recuerda que el _output_ (salida) también debe ir _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Comment: No te estas entendiendo con el sitio... vos posteaste la pregunta en dos lados distintos.. si conseguiste una respuesta en el sitio en ingles, genial!!!! pero los que entran a SO en español, esperan una respuesta en español. Tomate unos minutos agradeciendo a la comunidad traduciendo la respuesta que te dieron en ingles aca. Es perfectamente valido, aceptable y muy recomendable auto responderse las preguntas si encontraste una solucion. Luego de 24 horas, podes aceptar tu propia respuesta....

Comment: Entiendo. Ahora agrego un comentario con la solución. Mil disculpas.

Comment: buenisimo muchas gracias!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer estaba haciendo referencia al mismo objeto todo el tiempo, por lo que cada vez que se modifica uno, me modificaba todo el arreglo. entonces cada vez que llamo al evento debo crear uno nuevo.

```js
addMaterial(id:string){
  const mat = new materialModel();
  mat.id = id;
  mat.description = this.materialControl.description;
  mat.quantity = this.materialControl.quantity;
  this.materialControlList.push(mat);
}
```